# Clicking first item after sending keys

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click the first element I see after sending a key to an autocomplete text box, but cannot seem to be able to do this

I have tried

```
page_link = 'http://beta.compuboxdata.com/fighter'
chromedriver = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver'
cdriver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
cdriver.get(page_link)
elem = cdriver.find_element_by_id('s2id_autogen1')
elem.send_keys('Deontay Wilder').click()
```

and have tried this

```
cdriver.find_element_by_class('s2id_autogen1_search').click()
```

after sending the key to simulating clicking on the first item but to no avail

Comment: Did you add a wait condition before clicking the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

- On `elem.send_keys('Deontay Wilder').click()`, `send_keys()` return `None`, you can't use `click()` on it.
- The first option class is `'select2-result-label'`, not `'s2id_autogen1_search'`

You should also maximize the window and use `WebDriverWait`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

cdriver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
cdriver.maximize_window()
cdriver.get('http://beta.compuboxdata.com/fighter')

wait = WebDriverWait(cdriver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 's2id_autogen1'))).send_keys('Deontay Wilder')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'select2-result-label'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you can just tab your way to the first result:

```
elem.send_keys('Deontay Wilder')
elem.send_keys('\ue004')
elem.submit()
```